# LWC modal is not closing

Tags: apex, lwc

I created a LWC which works ok. I created this LWC so that I can use it as a Quick Action. Because LWC can not be used in quick actions for Work Order object, I had to put the LWC in a aura component and then put the aura in the quick action button. The one thing that is not working is the Cancel button. When I hit Cancel, it should close the modal. Also when I hit the submit button it should process the thing we are doing and then automatically close the modal. This close functionality is not happening. Can anyone please help?

LWC html

```
<template>
    
    <lightning-quick-action-panel>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 first-last-name">
                <label
                    class="slds-form-element__label slds-float_left your-info-label-field"
                    for="otherSubject">Please enter the zip code</label>
                <lightning-input type="text" variant="label-hidden" label="Zip Code"
                    value={zipCode}
                    onchange={handleZipChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
 
        <div slot="footer">
            <lightning-button variant="neutral"
             label="Cancel" onclick={closeAction}>
            </lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="brand"
             label="Add Order" onclick={saveAction} 
             class="slds-m-left_x-small">
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

LWC JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import {CloseActionScreenEvent} from 'lightning/actions';
import {getRecordNotifyChange} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getInfo from '@salesforce/apex/Order_QuickAction.getWipersInfo';
import addWoli from '@salesforce/apex/Order_QuickAction.addWipersToWO';
export default class OrderEntry extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track zipCode;
    @track wResponse;
    @track wPartNumber;
    @track wPrice = 0.00;



    handleZipChange(event){ //do I even need this method? I want to pass zip code value to a method that's why I have this 
        this.zipCode = event.target.value;
    }

    closeAction(event){
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }

    saveAction(){
        if(this.recordId){
            getInfo({workOrderId: this.recordId, zipCode: this.zipCode})
            .then(result => {
                console.log('the response is  '+ this.result);
                this.wResponse = result;
                this.wPartNumber = result.PartNumber;
                this.wPrice = result.Price;
                this.wPrice =  this.wipersPrice * 2;
                return addWoli({workOrderId: this.recordId, partNumber: this.wPartNumber, price: this.wPrice})
            }).then(result => {
                
                    getRecordNotifyChange( items [{recordId: this.recordId}]);
                    this.closeAction();
    
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error >>>> :: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                this.error = error;
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Aura Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:html tag="style">
        .slds-modal__container { min-width: 70vw; }
    </aura:html>
    <c:orderEntry recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

APEX:

```
public class Order_QuickAction {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static ResponseWrapp getWipersInfo (Id workOrderId, String zipCode){
        WorkOrder wo = [SELECT Id, Vehicle__r.Car_Id__c FROM WorkOrder Where Id =:workOrderId];
        System.debug('The card id is ' + wo.Vehicle__r.Car_Id__c);
        System.debug('The zipcode is ' + zipCode);
        System.debug('The response for wipers is ' +  OrderCalls.getWipers(wo.Vehicle__r.Car_Id__c, zipCode));
        return OrderCalls.getWipers(wo.Vehicle__r.Car_Id__c, zipCode);    //I have used this method in other places and it works it is also giving a response successfully so this method can't be the issue
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean addWipersToWO(Id workOrderId, String partNumber, Decimal price){
        WorkOrderLineItem woli = new WorkOrderLineItem();
        woli.WorkOrderId = workOrderId;
        woli.Part_Number__c = partNumber;
        woli.Type__c = 'Part';
        //woli.Quantity = 2;
        //woli.UnitPrice = price;
        woli.Part_Type__c = 'Wipers';
        insert woli;
        return true;
        
    }
}
```

Can someone please help and let me know why this modal is not closing? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

By default custom events doesn't bubble, nor are able to pass the boundaries of [shadow dom](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/08/how-events-bubble-in-lightning-web-components), so you should pass an object with both properties `bubbles` and `composed` setted to `true` to the `CloseActionScreenEvent` constructor, this way the event could crosses the shadow boundary and continues bubbling up through the DOM of the aura component, which will handle it closing the screen action.

```js
closeAction(event){
    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent({ bubbles: true, composed: true }));
}
```

By the way, there is an issue with `getRecordNotifyChange` in `saveAction` method:
`getRecordNotifyChange( items [{recordId: this.recordId}]);`
This line has a syntax error, it should be
`getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);`

Answer (score 0):

correct this will work.. you need to import

Call the `closeAction` in cancel button:

```html
<lightning-button
 label="Cancel"
 variant="neutral"
 onclick={closeAction}>
</lightning-button>
```

```js
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';

    closeAction() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent({ bubbles: true, composed: true }));
    }
```